# Problema con el $_GET[""]

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con el GET y no encuentro el porqué no funciona.

De primero tengo para que me guarde lo que haya en el get en una variable:

```
$error = $_GET["error"];
```

Después que me muestre el error dependiendo del número del get:

```
<?php

                    if ($error != "") {
                        ?>

                        <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
                            <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                            <span> 

                            <?php

                            if ($error === "001") { 
                                echo $CRError001;
                            } elseif ($error === "002") {
                                echo $CRError002;
                            }

                            ?>

                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <?php
                    }

                ?>
```

Aún así no me imprime el mensaje del error y no sé que puede estar pasando.

Comment: Tu variable `$_GET['error']` qué tipo de valor guarda, string o integer? Porque si no es string el operador `===` nunca se cumplirá ya que para que este se cumpla `$error` y `'001'` deben ser iguales y del mismo tipo (string)

Comment: Esto es lo que hace desde el otro documento 

if (!isset($_POST)) {
  
 } else {
  header("location: ../../index.php?error=001");
 }

Comment: `var_dump($error)` que te da?

Comment: Intenta quitar las comillas de tus comparaciones

Comment: esto me da el var_dump string(3) "001"

Comment: He probado quitando comillas, cambiando la forma de hacer los if's, etc. Y no consigo que imprima el error. Le estoy diciendo: if (isset($_GET["error"])) lo cual deberia de funcionar porque esta el get, y no funciona. No sé que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: Veo que en el html tienes `<div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">`, debería tener la clase `display-hide`? Por eso tal vez no muestra el error.

Comment: Será que `$CRError001` está vacío?

Comment: ¿De dónde sacas `$CRError001` y `$CRError002`? ¿Si pones `echo "Cualquier cosa";` sí se imprime? ¿No estarás ocultando el `<div>` mediante CSS?

Comment: Jemonge ese era el error -.-' perdonad mi retraso jajaja después de horas y horas mirando y probando, resulta que era esa etiqueta css... Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Comment: @CharlieClewer que bien que te funcionara. Agregué la respuesta para poder cerrar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje de error no aparece porque al `div` le estas aplicando una clase que lo oculta `display-hide`.

Si lo remueves debería de mostrarse el mensaje de error.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
    <span> 

    <?php

    if ($error === "001") { 
        echo $CRError001;
    } elseif ($error === "002") {
        echo $CRError002;
    }

    ?>

    </span>
</div>
```